# Pandas way to find discontinuous data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I will like to find out which columns in a pandas dataframe have discontinuous data. By "discontinuous" I mean that the values turn from some value to zero, before having some value again.

```
[0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0] # continuous
[0,0,0,1,2,0,4,5,0,0,0] # not continuous
```

I have managed to implement some code that can do this, using a for loop to iterate through every column of the dataframe. I made a working snippet below to show what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def find_discontinuous(series):
    switch = 0
    for index,val in series.iteritems():
        # print(val, end=" ")
        if switch==0 and val==0:
            # print("still zero")
            continue
        elif switch==0 and val!=0:
            switch = 1
        if switch==1 and val==0:
            # print("back to zero")
            switch = 2
            continue
        if switch==2 and val!=0:
            # print("supposed to be zero")
            return "not continuous"
    return "continuous"

data = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,5,0],
                 [0,1,2,0,4,5,0]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=list(range(7)),index=list(range(2))).transpose()

for column in df.columns:
    series = df.loc[:,column]
    res = find_discontinuous(series)
    print(column,res)
```

Output:

```
0 continuous
1 not continuous
```

I read somewhere that it is probably not correct to use a for loop to iterate through a pandas dataframe as it is slow. What will be the pandas way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: So, anything that's not discontinuous, is considered continuous? Something like all zeros would be continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check that between the first change away from zero and the last change to zero, there is no zero in between:

```
def is_continuous(series):
    id_first_true = (series > 0).idxmax()
    id_last_true = (series > 0)[::-1].idxmax()
    return all((series>0).loc[id_first_true:id_last_true] == True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform `df` with `apply` into `Series` with column names as index and `Boolean` value for `Continuous`:

```
df.apply(lambda y: not(any(map(lambda x: x[1] == 0 and x[0]>0 and x[2]>0, zip(reversed(y), reversed(y[:-1]), reversed(y[:-2]))))))
```

Alternatively you can use your function with `apply`:

```
df.apply(find_discontinuous)
#0        continuous
#1    not continuous
```